# Bash: Compare each line in for loop

Tags: bash, shell

I have a shell script that needs to analyze data from a file which looks like the following:

```
255  48  48             exp1
97  97  97              exas
238  44  44             dkopkw
194 194 194             sdkaok
```

I then take the data and sort it in a `for` statement. For each line I need to compare the data and see if it is less than *90* and prints a line between the numbers.

```
  #!/bin/bash

  for line in "$(sort /myfile.txt -k1 -n)"
  do

    COL_ONE=$(print "line" | awk '{print $1}')

    if [[ $COL_ONE -lt 90 ]]; then
            echo "$line"
            echo "------------------"
    else 
            echo "$line"
    fi

done
```

However, when this runs it does *not* print the line between the numbers. I want my output to look like the following:

```
97  97  97              exas
------------------------------
194 194 194             sdkaok
238  44  44             dkopkw
255  48  48             exp1
```

I am not sure what I am doing wrong and it has been driving me insane.

Comment: Each line has four fields, the first three being numbers.  This question should specify which of the first three fields (i.e. any of them, some of them, or all of them), are (or are not) to be compared to *90*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solution that bypasses the problems with your attempt and is more robust and efficient:

```
sort -k1,1 -n myfile.txt | awk '$1 < 98 { print $0 "\n------------------"; next } 1'
```

Note that I've used `98` rather than `90` as the comparison value, to be consistent with your desired output.
Also, note the `,1` added to `-k1` to ensure that sorting is truly limited to the 1st field.

---

As for what you've tried:

Leaving efficiency issues, the `98` vs. `90` issue, and ill-advised practices aside:

- If you *double-quote* a command substitution (`"$(...)"`) its output is treated as a *single* input to the `for` loop.

  - That said, omitting the double quotes isn't the answer, because [you shouldn't parse command output with `for`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor).
- `print` is not a Bash command (nor likely to be the name of an external utility, and `"line"` should be `"$line"` in order to reference the variable.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. My hair will now remain attached to my head.